# Marriage in the world to come?

Tags: marriage, olam-haba-world-to-come

As I understand it, in Judaism the soul waits in gan eden until the messiah comes and the people are resurrected ushering in the era of the  messiah. Will there be marriage in the world to come during this era? Please provide proof from the Talmud or other material.

Comment: There is a difference between the time of the arrival of the Messiah and the resurrection which arrives only later on. Are you asking about the former or the latter? In the former, there will be likely be marriages as the world will have similarities to what we know today, in the latter this is much less clear

Comment: Tell me about both. Is there like a treatise on this subject?